# Convert tfjs model for using in Tensorflow in c++

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I have one question, My project has two majors part, first written in NodeJs that train my model from dataset and save model to local storage, so I have two files:

1. model.json
2. wights.bin

The second part is written in c++, After couple of days I could build tensorflow with bazel and add it to my OpenCv project, so here is my question :

I want to train my model in NodeJs part and use these models in my C++ part. Is this possible ?
also I saw tjs converter but it converts models to use in NodeJs not vice versa.

**Update :**
After searching a lot I figured out that I should convert my models to protobuff file, but tfjs-Converter does not support this type of conversion and another point is that I want to use my model with opencv library.

**Update 2**
Finally I could change my model to .pb file, first I use tfjs_converter to convert to keras model(.h5 file) and after that use [this](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) python script to convert to .pb file and opencv can successfully load model. But I got this error in using model :

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   /tmp/opencv-20190505-12101-14vk1fh/opencv-4.1.0/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:524:
>   error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer
>   "flatten_Flatten1/Shape" of type "Shape" in function
>   'getLayerInstance'

Any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my own problem.

Here is the steps that I've done :

1. Convert my tfjs model to keras model using tfjs-converter
2. Using [this](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) python scripts to change keras(.h5) model to frozen model(.pb)
3. Use [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/183507/opencv-dnn-import-error-for-keras-pretrained-vgg16-model/) tutorial to optimize my .pb model

Finally everything works great!